# Write array to serial port

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, communication, code-review

The Code Below now works:

```
void SendCTRL (String &input) 
{
  const char *hin = input.c_str();    // Get character array
  int clen = input.length()/2;
  unsigned char cmd[clen+1]; // Leave a byte for null terminator
  for (int i=0; i < 2*clen; i+=2)
  {
    cmd[i/2] = dehex(hin[i])<<4 | dehex(hin[i+1]);
  }
  cmd[clen] = 0;                     // Null-byte terminator
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Transmit);  // Enable RS485 Transmit   
  for (int i=0; i< clen; i++)
  {
  RS485Serial.write(cmd[i]);   // Send string someplace
  //Serial.write(cmd[i]);
  }
  delay(clen/4);
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive);  // Disable RS485 Transmit
  Serial.println();

}

byte dehex(char c) 
{
  // Get nibble value 0...15 from character c
  // Treat digit if c<'A', else letter
  return c<'A'? c & 0xF : 9 + (c & 0xF);
}

byte dehex(char c) 
{
  // Get nibble value 0...15 from character c
  // Treat digit if c<'A', else letter
  return c<'A'? c & 0xF : 9 + (c & 0xF);
}
```

Input is a series of ASCII-encoded hex digits and getting the output to print the byte values of the hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some logic slightly askew with your length calculations:

```
int clen = input.length()/2;
```

Ok, so for a (say) 20 character string you have `clen=10`.

```
for (int i=0; i < clen; i+=2)
```

Ok, so for the first 10 characters of your 20 character string you take alternate ones (0, 2, 4, 6, 8)

What about the last 10 characters?  `clen` is 10, not 20, since you divided it by 2 at the start.

Decide if you want clen to be half the string length, then count *double*, or is the whole string length, and you divide it by 2 where you want the final string length. Or have two variables - one before and one after dividing by 2.

Oh, and you should pass your String parameter *by reference* so you don't duplicate the object and end up fragmenting your heap.

```
void SendCTRL (String &input)
```

I haven't gone into depth about the working of your `dehex` function, but this is the function I always use and works well:

```
unsigned char h2d(char hex)
{
    if(hex > 0x39) hex -= 7; // adjust for hex letters upper or lower case
    return(hex & 0xf);
}
```

Also you should *or* your values together, not *add* them:

```
cmd[i/2] = (dehex(hin[i])<<4) | dehex(hin[i+1]);
```

This would go some way to fixing your current issue, since `|` has a different precedence to `+`. At the moment you have effectively:

```
cmd[i/2] = dehex(hin[i]) << (4 + dehex(hin[i+1]));
```

since the `+` happens before the `<<`, whereas what you want is:

```
cmd[i/2] = (dehex(hin[i]) << 4) + dehex(hin[i+1]);
```

However with `|` instead you get

```
cmd[i/2] = (dehex(hin[i]) << 4) | dehex(hin[i+1]);
```

because the `<<` happens before the `|`

Here is your code written in pure C to run on a PC (faster to debug and test than an Arduino when you're on Linux):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char dehex(char c)
{
  // Get nibble value 0...15 from character c
  // Treat digit if c<'A', else letter
  return c<'A'? c & 0xF : 9 + (c & 0xF);
}

void SendCTRL (const char *hin)
{
  int ilen = strlen(hin);
  int clen = ilen / 2;
  unsigned char cmd[clen+1]; // Leave a byte for null terminator
  for (int i=0; i < ilen; i+=2)
  {
    cmd[i/2] = dehex(hin[i])<<4 | dehex(hin[i+1]);
    printf("%02x\n", cmd[i/2]);
  }
  cmd[clen] = 0;                     // Null-byte terminator
  for (int i = 0; i < clen; i++) {
    printf("%c", cmd[i]);
  }
}

void main() {
    SendCTRL("010307E40001C549");
}
```

Comment: Ok! that got the writing working. Unfortunately, it just seems to output jibberish.

Comment: I have posted my version of a hex to dec converter. It may work better, or may not...

Comment: @Majenko,  `c<'A'? c & 0xF : 9 + (c & 0xF)` will work with a...f as well as A...F as representatives of 0xA...0xF.  Also, Addition vs Or makes no difference here, because the low 4 bits of  `dehex(hin[i])<<4` are clear, and so are the high 4 bits of `dehex(hin[i+1])`.

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7 yes, it should all work fine in this situation - but it's good practice to get into the habit of combining with OR rather than with ADD.

Comment: Ok so my issue now is that my input string `010307E40001C549` should return me (as ASCII \code) `\01\03\07\E4\00\01\C5I` or (as U8) `[1,3,7,228,0,1,197,73]` Instead I'm getting (as ASCII) `\100~@\EE` any thoughts?

Comment: (as ASCII) `\100~@\EE` equates to (as U8) `[16,48,126,64,238]`

Comment: Because you're using `+` instead of `|` you have a precedence error. See my edit.

Comment: Switched to `|` for 010307E40001C549 I'm still getting  
(as ASCII) `\100~@\EE` equates to (as U8) `[16,48,126,64,238]`
Updated Code above

Comment: Maybe the Arduino compiler is doing it slightly different then. Add brackets around the first part of the combination formula.

Comment: Oh, and you are still confused with your counting. You now have `i++` instead of `i+=2` which is wrong. Check my example (pure c) code for how to do it.